# Where is the code that Devise generates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I installed the Devise gem into my Rails app, and ran `rails generate devise:install` and `rails generate devise User`.

Without my doing anything, the url `users/sign_up` already has a view somehow. The problem is, I can't find the template that is being rendered anywhere. It's certainly not under `app/views/users`. I chose some text on the page and ran a search for it within my app, and got back 0 results.

Then I tried to sign up with the form, and got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `current_sign_in_ip' for #<User:xxxxxxxxxxx>
```

I then searched for this controller, but there is no RegistrationsController in my app, and no Devise file. None of the files I'm looking for were generated by the two commands I mentioned above, either.

The [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) doesn't seem to shed any light on *where* the Devise code is kept.

Is the code even in my app? I'm so confused.

Comment: The amount of scaffolding that Devise "automagically" generates is quite astonishing, and the obscurity of it has recently had us make the decision to stop using it at work. You might want to look into some alternatives, like Sorcery, or Clearance (for simple username and password authentication.)

Comment: @Drenmi What do you use instead?

Comment: For now we are using Sorcery, but it comes with its own set of quirks and gotchas. I know some developers are proponents of rolling your own authentication, but that is a bit too extreme for us at the moment. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Devise, you're able to [generate the templates](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) which Devise depends on for logins, password resets, etc. using the following command:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This will create copies of the templates for Devise in your `views` directory.

For controllers, you can [access/override their functionality](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) by subclassing them in your own code. They're under the `Devise` namespace:

```
class NewRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # do stuff here
end
```

Then point the router to use this new controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'new_registrations' }
```

The code for the controllers can be found in Devise's [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise) - you can reference it to better understand what each controller is doing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So if I haven't generated the template yet, is `users/sign_up` using html from outside of my app? How is that even possible?

Comment: Devise operates as a Rails engine, so all its views are packaged inside the gem itself. You can see them [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise). That generator command creates copies of these templates within your views directory so that you're able to access/customize them at will.

Comment: So if I were to create my own controller `RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`....would that override the code coming from within the gem?

Comment: Yes, if you were to lets say define a `create` action within your new controller, with your own custom code, then that code would be used instead of Devise's original code. You could also keep the functionality of the controller methods and extend your own code on top of it using `super` - Devise documentation goes over some of this [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

Comment: No problem! And yeah, with a library as opinionated as Devise, you sometimes have to get your hands a bit dirty to provide overrides and to really customize behavior - but I think when it comes to authentication, an opinionated library isn't always a bad thing :P

Answer (score 2):

This is standard practice for Rails ["engines"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) (which almost all gems are) -

[image]

Think of them as [libraries](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/library.html) / [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361741/what-are-dependencies)... wherein they provide access to a lot of pre-compiled functionality through several hooks (often provided by an API).

---

One of the reasons I'd actually recommend people to [write their own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) is because it helps you appreciate how the whole thing works. [I wrote a gem](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler), [it uses `views`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/tree/master/app/views) just like Devise:

[image]

These views are not seen in the application because they're appended to your Rails app at runtime. It's basically how the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) var works in `cmd`, if you've ever had the pleasure of working with programmatic compilation etc.

Thus, Devise's "views" are stored in the Devise gem. This is appended to your Ruby installation... `[Ruby install dir]/lib/ruby/gems/[ver]/gems`, loaded at RunTime just like the `PATH` var...

[image]

Whilst you can generate your Devise views (as mentioned in the other answers), this is the base line of how it's able to access them without any prior references.

---

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `current_sign_in_ip' for #<User:xxxxxxxxxxx>
```

This means you don't have the `current_sign_in_ip` attribute for your Devise installation. I answered your question about this specifically here...
[Devise error: undefined method `current_sign_in_ip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008187/devise-error-undefined-method-current-sign-in-ip/33009047#33009047)

Answer (score 1):

All the devise MVC files are inside the gem. Below is my devise views directory. You could check yours as well. Go to your project root.

```
gem show 'devise'
/Users/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4
cd /Users/saurabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views
```

You can generate views in your project if you wish to customize.

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Answer (score 0):

All code of devise can be easily go through by [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and if you are using rubyMine you can view devise code in external libraries in devise folder.

To generate template for your model

```
rails generate devise:views
```

and then you can change your view as you want for your application.