# Devise error: undefined method `current_sign_in_ip'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I just installed Devise into my Rails 4.0.10 app. I wanted by users to be trackable, but I decided I didn't need `:current_sign_in_ip` and `:last_sign_in_ip`, so I removed those attributes.

My migration:

```
  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :initial_ip
  # t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
  # t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip
```

After I tried to make my first user, I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `current_sign_in_ip' for #<User:xxxxxxxxx>
```

I don't understand why `current_sign_in_ip` is even being called. Here's the "Create" action, which definitely doesn't include that method:

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

Why is `current_sign_in_ip` even being called at all?

Comment: Have you done `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: If you're using `trackable`, Devise expects those fields to exist and will try to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused because you've not got the `:current_sign_in_ip` and `:last_sign_in_ip` attributes in your data table.

This is the reason why:

```
 # t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
 # t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip
```

Commenting out those in your original migration has prevented them from being appended. You know this.

The way to fix, as mentioned in the answer by `mentanco` is to either put them back into the table, or to remove the [`:trackable`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) reference from Devise...

[image]

Here's how to get the migration to add the extra data:

```
$ rails g migration AddTrackingToUsers

#db/migrate/add_tracking_to_users_________.rb
class AddTrackingToUsers
   def change
      add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :string
      add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :string
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

If you run this, it will add the attributes to the table and get the functionality working again, alternatively, you can remove `:trackable` from your Devise model to allow it to skip the process entirely.

Comment: Great answer Rich. +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks for it, hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

you can't just not use them but if you remove them it will throw error because devise look for those attributes to update them after each sign_in:

```
 module Trackable
  def update_tracked_fields!(request)
    old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_at, Time.now
    self.last_sign_in_at = old_current || new_current
    self.current_sign_in_at = new_current

    old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_ip, request.remote_ip
    self.last_sign_in_ip = old_current || new_current
    self.current_sign_in_ip = new_current

    self.sign_in_count ||= 0
    self.sign_in_count += 1

    save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

so you have 2 options:

1. bring them back!
2. remove :trackable from the model then it won't call this module.

Comment: I see. How would you go about bringing them back? I can't just uncomment those lines in the migration and then run `rake db:migrate`, can I?

Comment: Add new migration with those fields and hit rake db:migrate, do not edit the migration you already run.

Comment: This is the answer, I'm updating with some more info